# Is it valid to use RestTemplate in 2023 with Spring Boot 2.7?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, microservices, resttemplate, spring-webclient

While searching for ways to connect my microservices, I noticed folks recommending WebClient because RestTemplate might get deprecated. But, in Spring 6, RestTemplate isn't deprecated yet. I don't need async in my project, so WebClient might just complicate things and add more headaches. Still, I want to avoid technical debt. What's the best move here?

I tried using WebClient for my project but I have Eureka in my project too so I noticed that Eureka is to be used with RestTemplate and making it work with WebClient needs some additional configuration.

Comment: `RestTemplate` isn't deprecated and has never been (AFAIK). It will only not get new features as it is in maintenance mode. Spring 6.1 gets a `RestClient` the non-reactive version of the `WebClient`.

Answer (score 0):

RestTemplate is not marked as deprecated but this can be found in the comments for it (from version 5.x - 6.0.x):

> NOTE: As of 5.0 this class is in maintenance mode, with only minor
> requests for changes and bugs to be accepted going forward. Please,
> consider using the org.springframework.web.reactive.client.WebClient
> which has a more modern API and supports sync, async, and streaming
> scenarios.

This has changed to (from version 6.1.x -):

> NOTE: As of 6.1, RestClient offers a more modern API for synchronous
> HTTP access. For asynchronous and streaming scenarios, consider the
> reactive WebClient.

So if you are able to upgrade and do not need the asynchronous and streaming scenarios you probably should use `RestClient` (https://spring.io/blog/2023/07/13/new-in-spring-6-1-restclient) to minimize tech debt.
Here is one quote from their announcement:

> Fourteen years ago, when RestTemplate was introduced in Spring Framework 3.0, we quickly discovered that exposing every capability of HTTP in a template-like class resulted in too many overloaded methods. In Spring Framework 5, we therefore used a fluent API for the reactive WebClient. With RestClient we are introducing a HTTP client that offers an API similar to WebClient, and that uses the message converters, request factories, interceptors, and other underlying components of RestTemplate.

This also skips the need for the `spring-boot-starter-webflux` dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you use RestTemplate, we may have to write separate instances for each api you are using from other services. better It would be good if you make use of Feign client or web client based on your project requirement.